# Is there a way to determine a user's current map view area?

Tags: android, ios, google-maps, apple-maps

Is there a way to determine a user's current map view area, whether in Google or Apple Map?

I'm in the process of designing a geolocation app, and want to show the names of locations near the user. I could use distance from user as the parameter, but want to see if there's a way to only show the names in the current map area that's being viewed instead. I've done a decent search but haven't found any method.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There's an object called VisibleRegion in the GoogleMap that gives you this information (Google Maps V2 for Android).  You get this from the GoogleMap object with the following code

```
VisibleRegion region = getMap().getProjection().getVisibleRegion();
```

I called `getMap()` to get the `GoogleMap` object because I was in the context of a `MapFragment`...not sure what your implementation is.

http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/VisibleRegion.html